# Public files downloading in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, download

I am using Rails-4.0.2, ruby 2.1.0 and have several public files, which are in my app/public folder. In index.html view I have the following form for downloading it.

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped" style="border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0; width: 50%;">
  <tbody>
    <% @reports.each do |report| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= report.title %></td>
        <td> <a href=<%= "#{report.url}"%>> Download </a></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

In the HTML code I have got the following link:

```
<a href="reports/2014-01-22-13:45:13-UTC.xlsx">Download</a>
```

When I am clicking on this link during development stage on 127.0.0.1:3000 browser is downloading this file. That is what I need.

But when I am clicking during production stage on the same address 127.0.0.1:3000 I have got the following error:

```
Started GET "/reports/2014-01-22-13:45:13-UTC.xlsx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-22 17:50:13 +0400
Processing by ReportsController#show as XLSX
 Parameters: {"id"=>"2014-01-22-13:45:13-UTC"}
 Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Report with 
 id=2014-01-22-13:45:13-UTC):
 app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:60:in `set_report'
```

This is just a static file in public folder, how can I download it in production?

Here is my config files:

### Development:

```
GetLead::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

### Production:

```
GetLead::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File won't be delivered in Production because

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

I recommend you use a real webserver (like nginx or Apache) to deliver static files! (As a starting point for configuring nginx see http://wiki.nginx.org/RubyonRailsMongrel or Google)